# Error while trying to run project: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I get a error when I try to run after builds for whatever type of project ever on Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

I have searched for a solution, but everywhere I look it seems to be a different error.

The code has nothing to do with this, I tried sample project and that did not work either.

Here is a picture showing the error:
[image: Error window in Visual Studio 2013 Professional]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to open the builds by locating them manually and launch the .exe.